# Magento 1.8 - can't use backend after upgrading extensions

Tags: magento-1.8, backend

I setup a fresh magento installation (1.8) and upgraded all extensions to their latest stable versions via Magento Connect Manager just moments after the installation. However, after it finished, I can't use the backend anymore.

It says: "Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in A:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php on line 111"

Caching is disabled and I already cleared the folder "var/cache".

[image]

How can I use the backend again?

Thats the code from the error:

```
/**
 * Define active menu item in menu block
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
protected function _setActiveMenu($menuPath)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml** file

```
...
<block type="adminhtml/page_menu" name="menu" as="menu"></block>
...
```

**menu** block definition should be there

If you think you have some extension overriding that try disabling them, one by one (so you can identify the responsible one), in **app/etc/modules**

Also, you can try downloading a fresh copy of your Magento version, and replacing all of your **app/design/adminhtml/default** folder

Comment: There is no "main.xml" file in that location.

Comment: That's the problem then

Comment: It seems like the upgrade triggered from Magento Connect Manager deleted many necessary files.

Comment: I tried to replace `app/design/adminhtml/default` with the fresh one, but it made no big difference, everything looks messed up. I decided to not research any longer, I will just start again from start and never use the bugged Magento Connect Manager again without using git.

Comment: ...and creating a database backup in prior.